# Is there a way to externalize the YYYY-MM-DD apiVersion in a resource declaration?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Consider this resource declaration:

```
resource storageAccountFileSvc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices@2021-09-01' = if (configureIHS) {
```

I am unfond of having to hard code a specific date into the resource declaration. Is there any way to externalize that?  I may have N occurrences of that kind of resource in my bicep files, why must I hard code the same value every time? I must update N occurrences when the arm-ttk tells me my version is too old.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per July 2022 this is not possible.

There are few discussions related on github that you probably want to folow:

- [Support "importing" resourceType and apiVersion mappings for specific resource types](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/16)
- [Support string interpolation in resource type string](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/413)
- [Addition of @Latest for Version and general change of APIVersion to Semantic Versioning](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/516)
- [Do *something* to make it easier to deal with resource types & api versions](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/622)
- [Using latest api version of a resource](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/1002)